# Weird Segmentation Fault in malloc() - C

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, malloc

Hello i am writing a program and i have declared a string in this way:

```
char *string=malloc(sizeof(char));
```

In my laptop i am using 64 bit Mint OS and everything is working fine.However in a 32 bit Debian machine i get in that line of code a segmentation fault.If i declare the string without malloc,like this: char string[100] the program is working fine.When i run the program with GDB it says malloc.c not found or something like that.Is this behavior logical?If someone has experienced the same issue before can please explain me why its happening?Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, it's normal that `malloc.c` is not found, unless you have installed the source for it and added to GDB's source path. There is little reason for doing so. It still works because the compiler links it against the binary, not the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to the other answer, I try to explain why it fails on 32 bit, but succeeds on 64 bit:

Most probably, your memory manager works with a certain granularity which depends on the word size of your system. Maybe it is 4 bytes on a 32 bit system and 8 bytes on a 64 bit system. (I am not sure if this is correct, however.)

If you allocate 1 byte, there are 3 resp. 7 bytes which are not used. So while you are not allowed to use them, nothing will happen.

If you use more than 3, but up to 7 bytes of them, nothing will happen on a 64 bit system, but on a 32 bit system, the program crashes.

Comment: I fail to see how this is the best answer. I could sum this up as: it's UB. :P

Comment: @netcoder I partially see it this way myself, but it is an answer for the part-of-question "Why does it work on 64 bit, but not on 32 bit?". And it shows why UB is unreliable, because it sometimes works and sometimes not.

Answer (score 3):

You are only allocating 1 byte for your string, so you are probably over-writing other variables or malloc heap structures.

Change:

```
char *string=malloc(sizeof(char));
```

to a more realistic size, e.g.:

```
char *string=malloc(256);
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer.I declared it char *str; but it was giving me a warning for uninitialized that's why i used malloc.I understand my fault here.But why although it has that error,it is working fine in 64 bit and not in 32 bit?

Comment: Just because something *appears* to work in one environment it doesn't mean that the code is correct - you just got lucky in one environment and not in another - that's all.

Answer (score 1):

To allocate a string of 100 characters you have to allocate 101 chars, the +1 is the end char `'\0'` so:

```
char *string = malloc(sizeof(char) * 101);
```

the `sizeof(char)` allow the create a char compatible for your operation system(65/32bit);
A char has always the same size in 64bit system or 32 bit system, however for the other type like `int`or `long` they have different size on a 32 or 64 bit!

Comment: "A char has always the same size in 64bit system or 32 bit system," - that's right. To be more precise, `sizeof(char)` always evaluates to 1 as required by the C standard. That's why I don't see its usefulness, except you create a macro...

Comment: @glglgl: In this case it's not useful, because we clearly see that `*string` is of type `char`, but it could be useful in cases where your declaration and your definition aren't at the same place (e.g.: C89), so that you don't have to always go back to the declaration to figure out what the variable's type is.

Answer (score 0):

From POSIX on malloc:

```
The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds shall be suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly freed or reallocated).
```

This is undefined behavior, but the explanation lies in the phrase 'suitably aligned'.
This is totally implementation defined, but it has to be at least on a word boundary for most architectures.

Assuming this to be true, then the size of a word could dictate where the next possible 'suitably aligned' memory location is:  4 bytes or 8 bytes away from the start of the allocated 1 byte buffer.

So it appears that the explanation, aside from this code has problems, is that the implementation allows writing to some bytes past beyond the end of what malloc, where 'some bytes' is a function of wordsize..